# Great Imagination (The beginning)

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

**First**, *I'm the largest*.

**Second**, *I'm lucky*.

**Third**, *I'm quite similar to infinity*.

**Fourth**, *I'm nothing*.

**Fifth**, *I'm lucky*.

**Sixth**, *I'm half of Third*.

**Seventh**, *I'm lucky*.

**Eighth**, *I'm like the Chinese elements*.

**Ninth**, *I'm like the musketeers*.

**Tenth**, *I'm both*.

**Eleventh**, *I'm lucky*.

**Twelfth**, *I'm half of Third*.

**Thirteenth**, *I'm like the musketeers*.

Google, and you shall find me.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*?

Reasoning

> 0 = I'm nothing
>   2 = I'm both
>   3 = I'm like the musketeers
>   4 = I'm half of Third (Third is I'm quite similar to infinity)
>   5 = I'm like the Chinese elements (wood, fire, earth, metal, water)
>   7 = I'm lucky
>   8 = I'm quite similar to infinity
>   9 = I'm the largest

This gives

> 9780747532743

Which

> when googled gives the title above. as Beastly Gerbil points out, it is the ISBN number

Also

> the puzzle title "The Beginning" refers to being the first in the series

Comment: Apparently it’s the ISBN (international standard book number) for that book

Comment: Yes, this is ofc correct!

Comment: What does it refer to by "I'm like the Chinese elements"?

Comment: @justhalf rot13(gurer ner 5 puvarfr ryrzragf (jbbq, sver, rnegu, zrgny, jngre)).  i'll add it